# Ошибка ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '', откуда она?

Tags: python

У меня есть мини игра, где программа загадывает число, а пользователь отгадывает его:

```
import time
import random
rand_number = random.randint(1, 20)
correct_guess = rand_number
attempts = int(1)
out_of_attempts = 6
win = False
print("""I am thinking of a 1-20 number.
You have 5 attempts. If you didn`t guessed correctly - you lose.
If you give up - input 25
Input 0 to leave.""")
while attempts < out_of_attempts: 
your_guess = int(input("Your {} guess: ".format(attempts)))
if your_guess == correct_guess:
    time.sleep(0.3)
    print("Correct!")
    win = True
    break
if your_guess == 0:
    print("Leaving now...")
    break
try:
    if your_guess == 25:
        print("Ha-Ha, I won! Correct number was {}".format (rand_number))
    if your_guess == ""
        print("Dont input empty guess.")
    elif your_guess > 20:
        print("Only numbers from 1 to 20.")
    else:
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print("Wrong!")
        attempts += 1
except ValueError:
    print("Only numbers, not literal.")  
if not win:
    print("You are out of attempts. Correct number was {}.".format(rand_number))
```

Попадается исключение: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Но я же написал действия при пустом вводе и такой ошибке, откуда она?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во-первых почините отступы, сейчас они у вас вообще пропали.
А во-вторых `try:` должен начинаться до `int(input(`, иначе он ошибки преобразования в `int` не поймает:

```
try:
    your_guess = int(input("Your {} guess: ".format(attempts)))
    if your_guess == correct_guess:
    ...
```